# error on deploy to sonatype:User missing promote permission for staging profile

Tags: maven, deployment, sonatype

I had upload jar to server, but I got below error. I had tried so many times.
[image]

And then I log into https://oss.sonatype.org/#stagingRepositories, I can see the list of Staging Repositories, but I cannot drop or release the repository. It said 403.
[image]

Could any one help me ? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your account doesn't have permissions to perform these actions.

This isn't the right place to ask for help with this, file an issue at https://issues.sonatype.org in the "Community Support - Open Source Project Repository Hosting (OSSRH)" project.